# For each row of dataframe check if duplicate values exist

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains following values:

```
URL                  Response.Code Count
www.site.com/page1   200             4
www.site.com/page1   301             1
www.site.com/page2   200             5
www.site.com/page3   301             4
www.site.com/page4   200             4
www.site.com/page4   403             1
```

For each unique value of URL I want to know if multiple values of Response.Code exist. If only one combination URL/Response.Code exist the URL is consistent. Desired output is a data frame like this:

```
  URL                  Consistent
  www.site.com/page1   FALSE
  www.site.com/page2   TRUE
  www.site.com/page3   TRUE
  www.site.com/page4   FALSE
```

I could do a loop for each of the unique URL's and check the number of different values in Response.Code, but it doesn't look like a very R way to solve this.

Any suggestions on the best way to solve this? I'm new to R & checked multiple questions on duplicates here but didn't seem to find a solution for this particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `base R` `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Response.Code~URL, df, length)[2] == 1

#     Response.Code
#[1,]         FALSE
#[2,]         TRUE
#[3,]         TRUE
#[4,]         FALSE
```

If you want output in required format then you can,

```
agg <- aggregate(Response.Code~URL, df, length)
new_df <- data.frame(URL = agg$URL, Consistent = agg$Response.Code == 1)
new_df
#    URL               Consistent
#1 www.site.com/page1      FALSE
#2 www.site.com/page2      TRUE
#3 www.site.com/page3      TRUE
#4 www.site.com/page4      FALSE
```

Comment: @DirkCeuppens - You could also put this all in the `aggregate` call `aggregate(Response.Code~URL, df, function(x) length(x) == 1)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'URL', we check whether the number of rows is equal to 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Consistent = .N ==1), by = URL]
#                 URL Consistent
#1: www.site.com/page1      FALSE
#2: www.site.com/page2       TRUE
#3: www.site.com/page3       TRUE
#4: www.site.com/page4      FALSE
```

Or if we are checking the `length` of `unique` elements in 'Response.Code' to be 1 we can use `uniqueN` after grouping by 'URL'.

```
setDT(df1)[, .(Consistent = uniqueN(Response.Code)==1), by = URL]
#                  URL Consistent
#1: www.site.com/page1      FALSE
#2: www.site.com/page2       TRUE
#3: www.site.com/page3       TRUE
#4: www.site.com/page4      FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

And we may as well go for the hat trick (base, data.table, and dplyr)

```
df1 <- structure(list(URL = c("www.site.com/page1", "www.site.com/page1", 
    "www.site.com/page2", "www.site.com/page3", "www.site.com/page4", 
    "www.site.com/page4"), Response.Code = c(200L, 301L, 200L, 301L, 
    200L, 403L), Count = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("URL", 
    "Response.Code", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))

df1 %>%
  group_by(URL) %>%
  summarise(Consistent = n_distinct(Response.Code) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your dataframe is called x, one thing that could work would be to run

```
x$consistent <- duplicated(x[,1:2]) | duplicated(x[,1:2], fromLast = TRUE)
```

which would check for duplicates in only the first two columns and write the TRUE/FALSE value to a new column. By default, `duplicated()` does not return `TRUE` for all instances of a duplicated row. By default, the first instance will be `FALSE` and all subsequent rows after the first instance will be `TRUE`. By making x$consistent TRUE with and without `fromLast = TRUE`, I ensure that all instances will end up `TRUE`.

If you want the output just as you've said, you would could run this to remove duplicate URLs and extra columns:

```
y <- x[!(duplicated(x$URL), c(1,4)]
```

This gets the result you're looking for, but if there's something else you're interested in, I'd suggest reading about `duplicated()` in the documentation.